# How to change behavior assigned to long-press of button on AirPods Pro 2

Tags: ios, airpods

At one point of using my AirPods Pro 2 (USB-C), I had found a setting in iOS 17.0 where I could choose the behavior assigned to a long-press of the button on ear bud.

I recall a choice between choosing to switch from Adaptive Audio to Noise Cancelling or from Adaptive Audio to Transparency.

I can no longer find this setting in iOS 17.1. Have I forgotten the setting location? Or has it been removed?

Answer (score 2):

When your AirPods are connected there is a row in Settings that show the AirPods icon and the device name. Tap on that and go to the section labeled "PRESS AND HOLD AIRPODS". There you can choose what holding the button does for left and right separately. You can set them to either adjust Noise Control, or to activate Siri.

There is also a section there to adjust call controls.

I am using iOS 17.1, and as far as I can recall this process hasn't changed from recent earlier versions. I am not using the same version of AirPods though, so your options may look a bit different (i.e. the adaptive audio option); I assume the general steps are the same though.

Here's an image I grabbed off a helpful [Mac Rumors article](https://www.macrumors.com/2022/06/06/ios-16-makes-it-easier-to-manage-airpods-settings/):
[image: AirPods settings]